# How can I remove Ubuntu 10?

Tags: windows-xp, ubuntu-10.10

Can I remove Ubuntu like this?

In Windows XP, right-click on My Computer → Manage → Disk management → right-click on Ubuntu partition → Delete logical drive

Can I do this or I not? If not please suggest an alternative.

Comment: Are you using the GRUB bootloader?

Comment: @klutch2: I'm so sorry! what do U mean?? I don't know!

Comment: When you boot up your computer, do you get a screen to select what you want to start up? Such as in your case. Ubuntu 10.10, Windows XP?

Comment: yes... a black screen with timer... and then I select OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as you said, but you will need to boot off of the Windows XP installation disc. When you get in there, usually you will need to click "R" to repair. The bootloader should then be repaired and you will be able to boot back into Windows XP normally without going through GRUB.

Answer (score 1):

That should do it.  Additionally, you may need to do an XP startup repair from the CD to get the boot loader back to the default XP one (How-To [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_5089290_restore-windows-xp-bootloader.html)).

Comment: I know... I want to remove Ubunto and install suse... which one is better to do???  with startup or manage ... ?

Comment: To get rid of it, you should do both what you suggested AND fix the boot loader.  Removing the partition kills the parition/files/data, fixing the boot loader reinstalls/resets the XP bootloader to stop referencing the other bootable OS.  Two different things, both needed to 'remove' an OS in a multi-boot config.